# Annotating WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with @Configuration causes config to be invoked twice

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-security, spring-ioc

When I create a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` it is getting registered twice. I've created a configuration exactly the same as the Hello [Web Security Java Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration) example from the reference docs.

The configuration is working as expected, though beans and the filter chain gets registered twice as shown in the tomcat output.

```
00:32:01 INFO : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
00:32:01 INFO : Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Oct 09 00:32:01 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
00:32:01 INFO : Registering annotated classes: [class com.acme.app.config.SecurityConfig]
______________
00:32:02 INFO : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@26eed435, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@cd9947, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@354e8394, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@54fb62e3, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1df9cd96, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@4da923c6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@1ee94efd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@7d4b5722, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@26dde6a8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7c58b660, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6fd12384, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@24d4cc75, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1709e92c, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2c46f137]
00:32:02 INFO : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 565 ms
00:32:02 INFO : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
00:32:02 INFO : Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Thu Oct 09 00:32:02 EST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
00:32:02 INFO : Registering annotated classes: [class com.acme.app.config.WebConfig]
______________
00:32:02 INFO : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@52b26dcb, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@10f4b535, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@561ad054, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@4b6e4b62, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1d424a71, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@2dad3bf4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@282a0f5c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@52eeebb7, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@47d4a88e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@474c5850, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6fdc40f8, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@2978de23, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5bf190dd, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@22b3fc11]
```

**AppInitializer.java**

```
public class AppInitializer
        extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("______________");
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }

}
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java**

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
        extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.acme.app")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieLocaleResolver getLocaleResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver bean = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        bean.setCookieName("clientlanguage");
        bean.setCookieMaxAge(100000);
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(lci);
    }

    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer getTilesConfigurer() {
        CustomTilesInitializer ti = new CustomTilesInitializer();
        TilesConfigurer res = new TilesConfigurer();
        res.setCompleteAutoload(true);
        res.setDefinitions("/WEB-INF/**/tiles.xml");
        return res;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.tiles();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addRedirectViewController("/home", "/");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/aboutme").setViewName("aboutme");
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

As @lkrnac has pointed out with [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26258804/140037) that the config is being loaded twice during the `WebConfig` `@ComponentScan` annotation. I had figured that spring would be smart enough to not load a config that it had previously loaded. I could locate the classes outside of the config namespace though that seems like a nuisance. Instead I have chosen to provide an exclude filter as in the following:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.acme.app",
               excludeFilters = {
                   @Filter(type = ASSIGNABLE_TYPE,
                           value = {
                               WebConfig.class,
                               SecurityConfig.class
                           })
               })
```

This way I can freely still create new config classes for my web context without having to worry about them being included or not.

Comment: what does your web.xml look like

Comment: There is no `web.xml` which is why I'm using `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Security config is in package `com.acme.app.config.SecurityConfig`. This package is scanned in `WebConfig`.

So I suspect that context is loaded twice:

1. In App Initializer
2. By Component scan in WebConfig

Try to locate `SecurityConfig` outside of `com.acme.app` package

Comment: Indeed you are correct, I had just also discovered the same thing. I figured spring would be smart enough to not load a config it had already loaded.

Comment: The solution hides the problem. A `@Configuration` class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and uses `@EnableWebMvcSecurity` is not a root application context and hence returning it from `getRootConfigClasses()` is bad design. Root context should not contain any web related beans – that’s what’s the `getServletConfigClasses()` is specifically meant for.

Comment: Hmm, interesting that Spring Security Docs are using this "bad design". Example here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous user on [my blog](http://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/10/avoid-component-scanning-of-spring-configuration/#comment-60529) pointed out to this excluding alternative:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.acme.app",
               excludeFilters = {
                  @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class)
               })
```

Comment: That will end up excluding all new `Configuration` classes, which you likely do not want.

Comment: I know, but can be handy as alternative. E.g. in my current app, in order to do integration testing of partial Configurations, I had configuration with component scan per package and imported them all into main one explicitly. So no global component scan.